# Random Variate Generation for the Gamma Distribution

Tags: r, distributions, simulation, gamma-distribution

Why am I getting the following error when I try random generation for the gamma distribution?

**The code I am trying to run:**

rgamma <- (n = 500, shape>= 1, scale = 1)

**This is the error I get :**

Error: unexpected ',' in "rgamma <- (n = 500,"

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to do is to generate 500 random variables with shape parameter greater or equal to 1, and scale parameter =1

Answer (score 1):

I will assume you are using R.

You are using the function "rgamma" incorrectly. The correct syntax is "myvector <- rgamma (n = 500, shape = 1, scale = 1)".

Also you cant use something like "shape >= 1". You need to give a fixed value to "shape".